# Django REST: Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: django, api, authentication, django-rest-framework, postman

There are similar questions like this on StackOverflow which didn't solve my problem. I'm using Postman to test my APIs. For some reason, my token authorization is not working and it's showing the following message,

```
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

My settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = { 
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

These are my installed apps:

```
...
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'dj_rest_auth',
'dj_rest_auth.registration',
...
```

I spent some hours to find the problem but failed. Can anyone please help me with where might the problem be?

Comment: There's not much I can do with this information, but did you include the authentication token in the headers in postman while calling the endpoint

Comment: Yeah... I've done that and even checked now to be sure again.

Comment: Are you added your host to ALLOWED_HOST ?

Comment: I'm using the localhost now.

Comment: have you tried with force_authentication https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication ?

Comment: Isn't that for development server only?